# How can I add conditional url variable using htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, variables, url, conditional-statements, addition

I use following code:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)post_type=product(&|$)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)product_cat=xyz
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/?%{QUERY_STRING}&product_cat=xyz
```

but it doesn't works.

I need to add variable "product_cat=xyz" where query_string contains "post_type=product" and it doesn't just contains "product_cat=xyz".

Examples:
If url is "http://www.example.com/?post_type=product&product_cat=xyz" then htacces leaves it unchanged.

If url is "http://www.example.com/?post_type=product" then htacces must add "&product_cat=xyz"

:-) Can you help me, please?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)post_type=product(&|$)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)product_cat=xyz(&|$)
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com/?product_cat=xyz [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Hi Croises... how can I also check if url not contains path "abc"? I need to apply rule also if url doesn't contains that path.

Comment: :-) sorry, my fault! I've just solved adding " RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/abc.* "